# Does minus operator and not exist result in same result in oracle

Tags: database, oracle11g, not-exists

Can anyone help to confirm that in oracle minus operator and not exists are returning same result set?

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's proof that the minus and the not exist queries do not return the same results:

**Minus Query**

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual)
select id, val
from   t1
minus
select id, val
from   t2;
```

**Minus Results**

```
        ID VAL
---------- ---
         1 a
```

**Not Exists Query**

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual)
select id, val
from   t1
where  not exists (select null
                   from   t2
                   where  t1.id = t2.id
                   and    t1.val = t2.val);
```

**Not Exists Results**

```
        ID VAL
---------- ---
         1 a  
         1 a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer